# 403 when clicking storage.cloud.google.com URLs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I'm trying to figure out the most appropriate [Google Cloud Storage IAM role](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) (that is not Admin) for being able to view objects in google cloud storage for auto-generating signed URLs when clicking links in this format `https://storage.cloud.google.com/xxxx.pdf`.

The objects are not public, and in our test environment, pasting a link like `https://storage.cloud.google.com/xxxx.pdf` in the browser would generate a signed URL, if the user is already signed in to Google, and is in some group (e.g. an engineer). If logged out, the URL would show a 403.

The roles and permissions set in the test environment are not as strict as in production, and as a result, regardless of what Google Group you're in, clicking such a link would give you a 403.

I'm aware of neater alternatives, however, given the nature of the feature (internal tooling), we were hoping this was just a case of assigning the correct permission.

I'm struggling to find the right terminology for what I'm describing (auto-signing? self-signing URLs?), but what role am I missing here, please?

I have of course already tried the objectViewer Role, and that did not work

Comment: I will try to rephrase: do you want to know how Google Cloud Storage generates a signed URL automatically if you have the correct credential?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere that's a much better way of saying it :) To add to your description, I'm specifically talking about accessing the storage.cloud.google.com link via a browser, rather than directly from the bucket object details screen (which works in production, but the latter doesn't)

Comment: Sadly, you can't. Your browser doesn't add automatically the security credential of the user. You have to use either the Google Cloud UI, that manage your credential, or use a signed URL generated by yourself (where the credentials are embedded in the signed URL). Nothing magic in the middle!

Comment: thought that might be the case, although we did see this work in our testing environment which gave me some hope. Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere